# Jmeter stops after amount of samples achieve threads count

Tags: macos, jmeter

I started the script with 100 threads, infinite loop count, 30 minutes duration and 200 ramp-up period. After amount of samples by every request achieve threads amount jmeter stops sending new requests. How to fix it?

jmeter 5.2.1,
macOS Big Sur 11.6

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT0wi.png)

Comment: Hi @Polina , Can you please check if you have any error in the `JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.log` ? What's the configuration of your machine?  Please note that It's recommended to use the latest version of JMeter. Can you include a screenshot of your Thread Group?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter GUI is for tests development and debugging only, when it comes to test execution you should (or even must) be using [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
./jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

when your test will be finished you can either open `result.jtl` file in the Listener of your choice or [generate HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) from it and analyze the outcome

During test execution all the Listeners should be disabled as [they don't add any value and just consume CPU time and other resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/).